# How to display results without two first lines

Tags: ubuntu, bash, grep, pipe, text

When I run some bash command it returns `2` .. `n` lines of text (`n` is different each time, may contain blank lines).

How to filter the output to display the result skipping lines 1 and 2?

e.g.

```
$ my_command

file1
file2
file3
file3

$ my_command | some_filter

file3
file4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ my_command | tail -n +3
```

In this case, the `+3` means "start output at the third line of the file".

Comment: `my_command | tail -n +3`

Comment: @Iain, The `-n` without a number following it doesn't do anything. The `-n` flag only matters when you want the last X lines of a file.

Comment: @ErikA: seems to matter on the centos and ubuntu systems I have to hand.

ls | tail +3

tail: cannot open +3 for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Huh, interesting. It works fine on a RHEL4 server without the `-n`, but not RHEL5 or Debian. Must have been a fluke in an old version of `tail`. I've edited my answer accordingly, thanks!.

Comment: I am curious now - does it work with -n +3 on the old server ?

Comment: Yep, works fine. Functionality is identical either with or without the `-n`.

Comment: The form without the `-n` is obsolete in GNU `tail` and `head` according to `info coreutils 'tail invocation'` (also documented in [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) ).

Comment: If your particular 'tail' command isn't playing ball, use: `awk 'NR>2 {print}'`